# What does this operatoer |= mean?

Tags: java, android, operators

in the following code in java :

```
Notification noti = nBuilder.build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

what is the this operator (`|=`) for ?

Comment: It just like +=,-= etc

Comment: `|= ` bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator `noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` is same as `noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

Answer (score 7):

```
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

means

```
noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

where | is the `Bit wise OR operator`

Answer (score 3):

- | is the bit a bit or operator
- |= is noti.flags = noti.flags |  Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

  noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

  calculates the bitwise OR of the noti.flags and  Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL, and assigns the result to noti.flagsd.

Answer (score 1):

bitwise or, is the same as:

```
noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

it executes an "or" operation with the bits of the operands. Say that you have

```
// noti.flags =                      0001011    (11 decimal)
// Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL =   1000001    (65 decimal)

// The result would be:              1001011    (75 decimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the bitwise OR with the assignment operator included.
Expanded it would be `noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`
Similarly you have &= for bitwise AND, ^= for bitwise XOR and ~= for bitwise NOT.